# Multiple Dicts w/ the Same Set of Keys

Tags: python

If I have multiple dicts that have the same set of keys (and nearly the same values), will the the two dicts have the same ordering of entries?  Or is the process of hashing not that predictable?

Comment: "multiple dicts that have the same set of keys".  Usually a terrible design mistake, by the way.  If you have multiple things with the same identification, you usually have multiple **attributes** of a single thing.

Comment: @S.Lott - what do you recommend?  The difference between the two entries is significant in meaning, but does not greatly affect size of entry.

Comment: Your question is thin on details.  It's difficult to make a more specific recommendation except to note that multiple parallel dictionaries is usually a terrible design mistake.  "multiple attributes of a single thing" was a complete recommendation.  I'll add words; perhaps the redundancy may be helpful.  Use a class.  Set various attributes so that there is one set of keys and each key is bound to thing with multiple attributes.  However.  It's impossible to be more complete, since the question is incomplete with respect t this specific issue.

Comment: @S.Lott - The wisdom of your post shines through like the smell of a single rose trapped in a Port-O-Potty.  Nonetheless, thank you - I will go the OOPython route.  +1.

Comment: It's not "wisdom".  It's just an observation that there may be room for improvement.  "The difference between the two entries is significant in meaning" may be relevant and be indicate that there's **nothing** wrong with the design.  The fact that you're trying to rely on the keys being in the same order indicates a fragile design, also.

Comment: Actually, you were right, though, as the two entries to the same key are always operated on together.  Having an object is going to be easier than passing multiple dicts throughout this program.

Comment: it is worth noting that the /hashing/ is always the same. order and hashing are not the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you can't expect the ordering to be same, since `dict` makes no guarantees about the ordering of its keys.

[`collections.OrderedDict`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) is designed to preserve the *insertion* order of its keys, so you could use that if ordering is important.

Comment: I will look at OrderedDict.  Thanks for the quick reply to my noob question.

Comment: There are two downsides to OrderedDict for this problem.  First, it has an overhead beyond the normal dict, though perhaps you don't care.  Second, (and a bigger deal), is that depending on this sort of thing can easily lead to fragile code.  You're better off looping over one dict's keys and then looking that key up in the other dict(s).

Answer (score 2):

It will depend on the order in which the entries were added to the dicts, AFAIK Python's `dict` data structure doesn't make any guarantee on the ordering of its entries.